# Result of tdclock in beamer is cut down

Tags: beamer, xetex, tdclock

I want to use `tdclock` in beamer and I use `xelatex` to compile it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[timeinterval=1]{tdclock}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\date[\tdtime]{\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \initclock
    hello \tdclock hi
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: tdclock in bottom bar]

[image: tdclock in text]

Comment: Just a guess: don't compile with xelatex, but with pdflatex.